# free non-gpl data compression libraries

Tags: c++, compression, zlib

i'm writing project that stores data, so i need to compress it. I've tried zlib but it's bottleneck of my project. So maybe there is faster solution. I don't need a great compress ratio, but i'm looking for really fast compression. Are there any other data compression libraries except zlib, that are really free and can be used in proprietary software (project, i'm working on, isn't GPL-based). My project is on C++ and I need to compress char* arrays of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few:

[FastLZ](http://www.fastlz.org/) -- fast and lightweight, MIT license unless you want to use it under a GPL license

[LZJB](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/common/os/compress.c) -- also fast and pretty lightweight, used as default compression algorithm for Sun's ZFS

Comment: Um, no.  lz4 is 50% faster at the same or better compression ratio than both FastLZ (https://code.google.com/p/lz4/) and LZJB (http://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/LZ4+Compression).

Comment: Just noticed that this is a rather old question.  Not sure why it showed up as recent.  Maybe because someone just edited it.

Answer (score 6):

A very fast compression algorithm is [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/). Benchmarks on the site show that decompression is comparable in speed to `memcpy()`.

The free version of LZO is GPL licensed, but there is also a commercial version of the library in [LZO Professional](http://www.oberhumer.com/products/lzo-professional/). Also, from the documentation:

> Special licenses for commercial and other applications which are not willing to accept the GNU General Public License are available by contacting the author.

Answer (score 5):

I think 7zip is public domain.  LZMA compression.

[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)

Comment: `7zip` is (much?) slower than either 'gzip' or 'bzip2'.  It's the usual trade-off- slower, but compresses better.

Comment: johne: Not necessarily. My E4500 compresses 100Mb roughly in about 10 seconds (LZMA compression).

Comment: `LZO` and `liblzf` approach `memcpy()` speeds- if I remember the E4500 XDBus backplane speeds correctly, they will both compress your 100Mb file in < 1 second.

Comment: It's typically slower than gzip, but faster than bzip2. It has better compression than both of them.

Answer (score 3):

Since you need something that is quick but not necessarily the best compression ever, you might consider a library that does RLE ([run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)) compression. One implementation is [librle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/librle/), which is under the BSD license, which is pretty permissible for proprietary use.

Answer (score 3):

Another answer already mentions `LZO`, which is sort of the default "I need faster (de)compression" solution.

Another one I've found is [liblzf](http://oldhome.schmorp.de/marc/liblzf.html).  Pretty close to `LZO` in terms of speed and compression rates. `LZO` has a GPL license, whereas `liblzf` has a BSD license (which, IMHO, is an advantage).

Answer (score 3):

Google has released "Snappy", which is a BSD licensed compression library written in C++ (bindings in C included).

http://code.google.com/p/snappy/

According to README in the source:

> In our tests, Snappy usually is faster than algorithms in the same
>   class (e.g. LZO, LZF, FastLZ, QuickLZ, etc.) while achieving
>   comparable compression ratios.

Answer (score 3):

Due to issues with LZO licensing we decided to evaluate the suggestions in this thread that are BSD/MIT licensed, are very similar to LZO (for easier integration) and are suitable to run on low end hardware (think inexpensive 32bit MCUs, not Pentium2).

We tested LZ4, LZF, FastLZ and compared the results to LZO. We compressed graphical data. I cannot post exact results, but **LZ4 was considerably faster than others** (wins in 7 tests, with up to 40% margin against the second best), while matching the size (5-2-2 wins for LZF-LZ4-LZO, margins were small).

Answer (score 3):

I second [lz4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/).  It has a BSD license.

Answer (score 2):

[Intel Integrated Performance Primitives](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-code-samples/#dc) has samples that implements variety of compressions:

> - bzip2-compatible library
>       The ipp_bzip2 sample demonstrates how to use Intel IPP Data Compression domain functions for implementation of bzip2/libbzip2 (a program and library for lossless, block-sorting data compression and new improvements on threading optimization for bzip
> - GZIP-compatible library
>       The IPP_GZIP sample illustrates the way of implementing effective lossless data compression solution by using Intel IPP Data Compression domain API. Additionally, this sample shows the ways of parallelizing application using OpenMP and other methods to advanced benefits on multi-core environment.
> - zlib-compatible library (new!)
>       This code sample illustrates how to build a zlib-compatible data compression library using the optimized LZ77 and Huffman coding functions in Intel IPP.
> - General data compression examples
>       Illustrates how to use functions provided by the Intel IPP data compression domain. Includes Huffman encoding/decoding, RLE encoding/decoding, MoveToFront (MTF), Burrows-Wheeler Transformations (BWT), General Interval Transform (GIT), and Lempel-Ziv-Storer-Szymanski (LZSS) functions.

IPP is not free, but it really fast. It supports Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I have used a [LZSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Storer%E2%80%93Szymanski) [implementation](http://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/compression/lzss.c) from [Haruhiko Okumura](http://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/). The licensing is not clear from his site but [some](http://wiki.awkwardtv.org/wiki/LZSS) [versions](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/2260/4/ZipView.aspx) was released with a "Use, distribute, and modify this program freely" line included and the code is used freely by commercial vendors.

Another option could be the [lzfx](http://code.google.com/p/lzfx/) lib that implement LZF. It is released under a BSD Licence.

Comment: Haruhiko Okumuras page says: `Except where otherwise noted, content on this site is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.1 Japan License.`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bzip2 has a BSD license.

Comment: bzip2 is generally slower than gzip, though with better compression